# Publish ASP.NET Core from Visual Studio to Linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio, .net-core, publish

Can I edit a ASP.NET Core application in Visual Studio and deploy to Linux server (e.g., [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29))?

Answer (score 9):

You can check this page in the ASP.NET CORE documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction

A good example can also be found in this blog post from Scott Hanselman - https://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNETCoreWebsiteToACheapLinuxVMHost.aspx

I currently use my own batch script to deploy which follows these steps:

1. Publishes the app using dotnet publish command.
2. Zips everything using Powershell.
3. Copies the zip to the Linux machine using pscp - [https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html)
4. Connects to the Linux machine using Windows Bash (you need Windows 10 Anniversary Update for this feature to be available).
5. Calls the unzip command on the Linux machine - needs to be installed there first.
6. Restarts the supervisor service on the Linux machine.

**EDIT:**
I have added the version of my script which I used when I posted my original answer as requested by [Andrew Basarab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5338908/andrew-basarab). I'm sure it needs some refactoring considering my poor scripting knowledge back then. Please use with caution:

```
@echo off

set PrivateKeyLocation="C:\fakepath\fakefile.ppk {private key for connecting to the remote Linux machine}"
set CertificateFileLocation="/mnt/c/fakepath/fakefile.pem {same key used to execute remote bash commands from my Windows machine}"

for %%* in (.) do set CurrentDirName=%%~nx*
set OutputFolder="%tmp%\%CurrentDirName%"
set OutputZipFile="%tmp%\%CurrentDirName%.zip"
set RemoteHost="ubuntu@54.142.181.122 {remote host address}"
set RemoteLocation="/home/ubuntu {the location to copy the output to}"

dotnet publish -o "%OutputFolder%"

powershell -command "& {&'Compress-Archive' -Path %OutputFolder% -DestinationPath %OutputZipFile%}"
rmdir /s /q %OutputFolder%

pscp -i %PrivateKeyLocation% -pw {private key password} %OutputZipFile% %RemoteHost%:%RemoteLocation%
del /q %OutputZipFile%

bash -c "ssh -i %CertificateFileLocation% %RemoteHost% 'sudo rm -rf %CurrentDirName% ; unzip %CurrentDirName%.zip ; rm -r %CurrentDirName%.zip ; sudo service supervisor restart'"
```

Some tools and services need to be installed on both machines. Please refer to the aforementioned post by Scott Hanselman.

Comment: Can you please share your bash script? I have the same need and at the moment it takes a lot of time to do all these steps manually using WinSCP.

Comment: @AndrewBasarab, I have just added the script to my answer post. I did that long time ago and don't really remember the details, so please use that script with caution.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how your can deploy *from* Visual Studio to Ubuntu server, but if you have access to the server (for instance with SSH) you can simply pull your code from a Git's repository, then compile, publish and run.