# Deploying .net core app to Ubuntu using VSTS

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Service Fabric app with a bunch of .net core 2.1 services, all happily deploying to a windows cluster. I haven't created the Ubuntu service fabric instance yet, but wanted to understand the processes involved first.

I'd now like to experiment with pushing out the app to an Ubuntu Service Fabric cluster. To this end I have added the Ubuntu runtime identifier to the .csproj (it now has Ubuntu and win7-64 declared).

Can someone tell me if I need to do something in my VSTS build when building/packaging the service fabric app? Presumably the build process needs to know that I want to deploy to an Ubuntu cluster rather than Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pleas refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-core?view=vsts&tabs=gitvsts%2Cweb%2Cdeploy-linux) to Build your ASP.NET Core app

If you don't want to use the `Hosted Linux` Agent, then you need to [Deploy an agent on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=vsts) (Ubuntu here) first.

Then try to use VSTS and Docker to Build and Deploy ASP.NET Core to Linux.

Please see [Continuous Delivery with Containers – Use Visual Studio Team Services and Docker to Build and Deploy ASP.NET Core to Linux](https://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-with-containers-use-visual-studio-team-services-and-docker-to-build-and-deploy-asp-net-core-to-linux/) for details.

You can also reference below articles:

- [Building, deploying and testing an ASP.NET Core application in a
  Docker container on Linux using the TFS2015 task-based build
  system](https://blogs.infosupport.com/build-deploy-test-aspnetcore-docker-linux-tfs2015/)
- [Build and Deploy Your ASP.NET Core Application with Apache](https://developer.telerik.com/topics/net/build-deploy-asp-net-core-application-apache/)
- Also, there is a video here which introduced the [CI/CD pipeline for an
  ASP.NET Core Application to deploy to Linux with VSTS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ng11ElnXfPg)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you tell me why I need to use a Linux build agent? I was under the impression I could build a .net core app on Windows and deploy to Linux.

Comment: @Slicc As the simplest way is build with the Linux build server. If you just need to build app on windows and deploy to Linux, then you can try to zip the files and copy the zip to the Linux machine, then unzip to deploy... You can reference this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254478/publish-net-core-mvc-from-visual-studio-to-linux